# linking with static library in C

Tags: c, linker, static-linking

Hi I'm a beginner in C and Linking, I was reading a book that has a question in linking with static library:

> Let a and b denote object modules or static libraries in the current directory, and
>   let a→b denote that a depends on b, in the sense that b defines a symbol that is
>   referenced by a. For each of the following scenarios, show the minimal command
>   line (i.e., one with the least number of object file and library arguments) that will
>   allow the static linker to resolve all symbol references:
>
> ```
> p.o → libx.a → liby.a and liby.a → libx.a →p.o
> ```

and the answer given by the book is:

```
gcc p.o libx.a liby.a libx.a
```

I'm confused, shouldn't the answer be :

```
gcc p.o libx.a liby.a libx.a p.o
```

otherwise how the undefined symbol in `libx.a` resolved by `p.o`?

Comment: You don't need to and you should not specify object files twice when passing them to `gcc`. Read [*Linkers and Loaders*](https://www.iecc.com/linkers/) and the documentation of [`ld`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/) and of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: It's also incredibly weird that a library would have a dependency on your `.o` file.

Comment: I'm not sure. I carefully try to prevent such circular dependencies of libraries. Instead, I always try to organize things clear hierarchically. Hence, I've never been in such a situation like described in your book (and hopefully will never be) and actually don't know how to handle this properly. Btw. I'm not the only one who organizes software neatly in layers: [Example: Linux graphical desktop environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus#/media/File:Free_and_open-source-software_display_servers_and_UI_toolkits.svg).

Comment: @Scheff sorry another linking question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153834/how-linkers-resolve-multiply-defined-global-symbols-in-c/53153920#53153920    could you have a look please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your C textbook does not make it clear, the linkage
behaviour that the author is attempting to illustrate with this
exercise is not mandated by the C Standard and is in fact behaviour
of the GNU `binutils` linker `ld` - the default system linker in Linux,
usually invoked on your behalf by `gcc|g++|gfortran`, etc - and possibly
but not *necessarily* the behaviour of other linkers you might encounter.

If you've given us the exercise accurately, the author may be someone who does not understand static
linking quite as well as would be best for writing textbooks about it, or perhaps just doesn't
express themselves with great care.

Unless we are linking a *program*, the linker by default will not
even insist on resolving all symbol references. So presumably we're
linking a program (not a shared library), and if the answer:

```
 gcc p.o libx.a liby.a libx.a
```

is actually what the text-book says, then a program is what it has to be.

But a program must have a `main` function. Where is the `main` function
and what are its linkage relationships to `p.o`, `libx.a` and `liby.a`? This
matters and we're not told.

So let's assume that `p` stands for *program*, and that the main function is at
least defined in `p.o`. Weird though it would be for `liby.a` to depend
on `p.o` where `p.o` is the main object module of the program, it would be even
weirder for the `main` function to be defined in a member of a static library.

Assuming that much, here are some source files:

**p.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void x(void);

void p(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}

int main(void)
{
    x();
    return 0;
}
```

**x.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void x(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**y.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void y(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**callx.c**

```
extern void x(void);

void callx(void)
{
    x();
}
```

**cally.c**

```
extern void y(void);

void cally(void)
{
    y();
}
```

**callp.c**

```
extern void p(void);

void callp(void)
{
    p();
}
```

Compile them all to object files:

```
 $ gcc -Wall -Wextra -c p.c x.c y.c callx.c cally.c callp.c
```

And make static libraries `libx.a` and `liby.a`:

```
$ ar rcs libx.a x.o cally.o callp.o
$ ar rcs liby.a y.o callx.o
```

Now, `p.o`, `libx.a` and `liby.a` fulfil the conditions of the exercise:

```
 p.o → libx.a → liby.a and liby.a → libx.a →p.o
```

Because:

- `p.o` refers to but does not define `x`, which is
   defined in `libx.a`.
- `libx.a` defines `cally`, which refers to but does not define `y`,
  which is defined in `liby.a`
- `liby.a` defines `callx`, which refers to but does not define `x`,
  which is defined in `libx.a`.
- `libx.a` defines `callp`, which refers to but does not define `p`,
  which is defined in `p.o`.

We can confirm with `nm`:

```
 $ nm p.o
 0000000000000000 r __func__.2252
                  U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
 0000000000000013 T main
 0000000000000000 T p
                  U puts
                  U x
```

`p.o` defines `p` ( = `T p`) and references `x` ( = `U x`)

```
$ nm libx.a

x.o:
0000000000000000 r __func__.2250
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U puts
0000000000000000 T x

cally.o:
0000000000000000 T cally
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U y

callp.o:
0000000000000000 T callp
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U p
```

`libx.a` defines `x` ( = `T x`) and references `y` ( = `U y`) and
references `p` ( = `U p`)

```
$ nm liby.a

y.o:
0000000000000000 r __func__.2250
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U puts
0000000000000000 T y

callx.o:
0000000000000000 T callx
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U x
```

`liby.a` defines `y` ( = `T y`) and references `x` ( = `U x`)

Now the textbook's linkage certainly succeeds:

```
$ gcc p.o libx.a liby.a libx.a
$ ./a.out
x
```

But is it the shortest possible linkage? No. This is:

```
$ gcc p.o libx.a
$ ./a.out
x
```

Why? Lets rerun the linkage with diagnostics to show which of our object
files were actually linked:

```
$ gcc p.o libx.a -Wl,-trace
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o
p.o
(libx.a)x.o
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtendS.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

They were:

```
 p.o
 (libx.a)x.o
```

`p.o` was first linked into the program because an input `.o` file is
*always* linked, unconditionally.

Then came `libx.a`. Read
[static-libaries](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info)
to understand how the linker handled it. After linking `p.o`, it had
only one unresolved reference - the reference to `x`. It inspected `libx.a` looking for an
object file that defines `x`. It found `(libx.a)x.o`. It extracted `x.o` from `libx.a`
and linked it, and then it was *done*.<sup>1</sup>

All of the dependency relationships involving `liby.a`:-

- `(libx.a)cally.o` depends on `(liby.a)y.o`
- `(liby.a)callx.o` depends on `(libx.a)x.o`

are irrelevant to the linkage, because the linkage does not *need* any
of the object files in `liby.a`.

Given what the author says is the right answer, we can reverse engineer the
exercise that they were striving to state. This is it:

- An object module `p.o` that defines `main` refers to a symbol `x` that it
  does not define, and `x` is defined in member `x.o` of a static library `libxz.a`
- `(libxz.a)x.o` refers to a symbol `y` that it does not define, and `y` is defined in member `y.o` of a static library `liby.a`
- `(liby.a)y.o` refers to a symbol `z` that it does not define, and `z` is defined in member `z.o` of `libxz.a`.
- `(liby.a)y.o` refers to a symbol `p` that it does not define, and `p` is defined in `p.o`
- What is the minimal linkage command using `p.o`, `libxz.a`, `liby.a`
  that will succeed?

New source files:

**p.c**

```
Stays as before.
```

**x.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void y();

void cally(void)
{
    y();
}

void x(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**y.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void z(void);
extern void p(void);

void callz(void)
{
    z();
}

void callp(void)
{
    p();
}

void y(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**z.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void z(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

New static libraries:

```
$ ar rcs libxz.a x.o z.o
$ ar rcs liby.a y.o
```

Now the linkage:

```
$ gcc p.o libxz.a
libxz.a(x.o): In function `cally':
x.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `y'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

fails, as does:

```
$ gcc p.o libxz.a liby.a
liby.a(y.o): In function `callz':
y.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `z'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and:

```
$ gcc p.o liby.a libxz.a
libxz.a(x.o): In function `cally':
x.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `y'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and (your own pick):

```
$ gcc p.o liby.a libxz.a p.o
p.o: In function `p':
p.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `p'
p.o:p.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
p.o: In function `main':
p.c:(.text+0x13): multiple definition of `main'
p.o:p.c:(.text+0x13): first defined here
libxz.a(x.o): In function `cally':
x.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `y'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

fails with both undefined-reference errors *and* multiple-definition errors.

But the textbook answer:

```
$ gcc p.o libxz.a liby.a libxz.a
$ ./a.out
x
```

is now right.

The author was attempting to describe a *mutual dependency* between two
static libraries in the linkage of a program, but fumbled the fact that such a mutual dependency
can only exist when the the linkage *needs* at least one object file from *each* library that
refers to some symbol that is defined by an object file in the *other* library.

The lessons to be learned from the corrected exercise are:

- An object file `foo.o` that appears in the linker inputs never needs to appear
  more than once, because it will be linked *unconditionally*, and when it is
  linked the definition that it provides of any symbol `s` will serve to resolve
  all references to `s` that accrue for any other linker inputs. If `foo.o` is
  input twice you can only get errors for multiple-definition of `s`.
- But where there is a mutual dependency between static libraries in the linkage
  it *can* be resolved by inputting one of the libraries twice. Because an object file
  is extracted from a *static library* and linked if and only if that object file is
  *needed* to define an unresolved symbol reference that the linker is seeking to define
  *at the point when the library is input*. So in the corrected example:

  - `p.o` is input and unconditionally linked.
  - `x` becomes an unresolved reference.
  - `libxz.a` is input.
  - A definition of `x` is found in `(libxz.a)x.o`.
  - `(libxz.a)x.o` is extracted and linked.
  - `x` is resolved.
  - But `(libxz.a)x.o` refers to `y`.
  - `y` becomes an unresolved reference.
  - `liby.a` is input.
  - A definition of `y` is found in `(liby.a)y.o`.
  - `(liby.a)y.o` is extracted and linked.
  - `y` is resolved.
  - But `(liby.a)y.o` refers to `z`.
  - `z` becomes an unresolved reference.
  - `libxz.a` is input *again*.
  - A definition of `z` is found in `libxz.a(z.o)`
  - `libxz.a(z.o)` is extracted and linked.
  - `z` is resolved.

---

[1] As the `-trace` output shows, strictly speaking the linkage was not
done until all the boilerplate following `(libx.a)x.o` was also linked,
but it's the same boilerplate for every C program linkage.

Comment: thank u for your answer, could you also have a look at this linking question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153834/how-linkers-resolve-multiply-defined-global-symbols-in-c/53153920#53153920

Comment: @amjad I have looked at it. As other readers have commented, to get more helpful replies you need to edit that question to tell us what version of gcc you are using (the output of `gcc --version`).