# How Linkers Resolve Multiply Defined Global Symbols in C

Tags: c, linker, operating-system, static-linking

My Textbook says that:

*"Functions and initialized global variables get strong symbols. Uninitialized global variables get weak symbols.Given a strong symbol and multiple weak symbols, choose the strong symbol"*

So I create two files to see:

file1.c:

```
int number;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    printf("%d",number);
    return 0;
}
```

file2.c (just one line):

```
int number = 2018;
```

and I ran `gcc -Wall -o program file1.c file2.c` and the output is 0, which I can understand before I study linker ('number' in file1.c has been initialized to 0), but after I study how linker works, I start to wonder why the output is not 2018, since the 'number' in file2 is strong symbol(initialized global variable) and the 'number' in file1 is weak symbol, so the linker will choose the strong one whose value is 2018, so why the linker choose the weak symbol?

Comment: What toolchain are you using? I think this is UB as per the standard, but I'm pretty sure most linkers will make `int number;` a so-called "common" symbol, which in the presence of a strong symbol will get merged replaced by the strong one. I'm getting 2018 with all tinycc, gcc and clang.

Answer (score 4):

The `int number;` in file1.c is not uninitialized. Note that it is declared at file scope, it is declared without an initializer, and it is declared without a storage-class specifier (particularly no `extern` or `static`). Then C 2018 6.9.2 2 says:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier `static`, constitutes a *tentative definition*. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

So, for purposes of initialization, `int number;` in file1.c is the same as `int number = 0;`. It is initialized.

An issue with the text you quote is that it is describing the linker using terminology for that linker, and this is different terminology than the the C standard uses. The C standard does not have any “global” variables or “strong” or “weak” symbols.

Comment: Isn't int number; declared at global scope?

Comment: @nicomp: The C standard does not have any scope that is “global scope.” There is file scope and external linkage. An identifier that is declared outside of any block or list of parameters has file scope.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, but if int number in file1.c is the same as int number = 0, then we have two strong symbol, shouldn't the linker throw an error when it encounters more than one strong variable, I mean an error of "multiple definition of ‘number’

Comment: @amjad: Per C 2018 6.9 5, there shall be no more than one definition of an external object in the entire program. Per 4 2, violating a “shall” has behavior not defined by the C standard. So the C implementation is permitted to do anything here, including completing the link. In my case (macOS 10.13.6 with Xcode 9.4.1), “2018” is printed, and I believe the tools are using a long-established Unix behavior where the explicitly initialized object prevails (in effect, Unix has extended C by defining the behavior the C standard does not define). You should state the tools you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The `number` in file2.c is global, but still locally scoped just to that file. If you want file1.c to use `number` from file2.c you need to mark it as `extern` like this:

```
extern int number;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    printf("%d",number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry I don't get it, if a global variable without a static keyword, then it is globally scope, and can be accessed by the program, otherwise why do we need static keyword to limit access by other modules?

Comment: The C standard does not use “global” for scope or linkage. You may mean that `number` in file2.c has external linkage but file scope.